# Joining words in speech with vowel ending/start

Tags: sentence-construction

To join words with vowel endings during speech, for example in French there is " Aime-t-elle, parle-t-il ?"  etc. Among Indian languages also one finds such liasons automatically adopted.

In English we have only a few such words like "naïve","co-ordinate","coördinate" and so on part of the same word intoned discontinuously .. or so it may appear to one not so used to it. Just wondered.

Comment: What do you mean by "inconveniently expressed"? The use of diacriticals which many people can't interpret or reproduce in typing?  Likewise for "pushed through"—what do you mean?  And I have no idea where these are "separately kept".

Comment: No, I refer to speech block, a pause, a discontinuity in guttural delivery that affects speed, quite minor though.  Sanskrit mantras have such pauses aplenty, but that is exempted for an ancient  language.Kept apart in the same word and pronounced as such.

Comment: @Narasimham Please edit your question to include that "discontinuity" you named, so answerers don't have to read the comments to figure out what you are asking.

Comment: " coördinate" is not an English word.

Comment: @Narasimham You may be interested to hear sample pronunciations of [naïve](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/naive) and [coordinate](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/coordinate_1) given by Macmillan Dictionary. Do you think there is a discontinuity (that you mentioned) in the two examples?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem At one time this spelling was [quite common](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHWA_enUS630US630&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=co%C3%B6rdinate&tbm=bks).

Comment: This is an interesting question, but until I read StoneyB's answer I wasn't sure what you were talking about. It would help all users of the website if your questions contained an actual question (and by that I don't mean a statement with a question mark at the end). It's more effective if people spend time on answering your question than on wrapping their heads around what the actual question is :-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "discontinuity" you're talking about appears to be the glottal stop, IPA /ʔ/, and it's never been represented in English orthography because it's not a phoneme: it's driven by phonetic context.

And the orthographic words you cite aren't really notating the glottal stop: they exhibit various orthographic expedients for preventing the reader from understanding two adjacent vowels in their conventional sense. When ‹coordinate› was a new word in English it *looked* like a word beginning with ‹coor›, so writers were careful to indicated that it was a compound of ‹ordinate› with the prefix ‹co›. The spelling ‹naïve› is designed to forestall pronunciation as /neɪf/, rhyming with ‹safe›. Nowadays these expedients are rarely employed, because the words are quite familiar.